# Creating a table in an H2 database by booting a spring boot app

Tags: java

The table is not being created in h2 when booting the spring boot app

I created the mapping mojo class. Added the correct entries in application.properties. And also started the h2 database.

pojo class:

```
   package entities;

    import java.sql.Timestamp;

    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;

    @Entity
    public class links {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long userId;
        private String username;
        private String userAccountName;
        private String userPassword;
        private Integer age;
        private Timestamp setupTimestamp;
        private Integer weightInPounds;
        private Integer heightInCm;
        private String diet;
        private String intolerances;
        private Integer mealId;
        private Integer routineId;

        public links() {
            super();
        }
        public Long getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }
        public void setUserId(Long userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }
        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
        public String getUserAccountName() {
            return userAccountName;
        }
        public void setUserAccountName(String userAccountName) {
            this.userAccountName = userAccountName;
        }
        public String getUserPassword() {
            return userPassword;
        }
        public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
            this.userPassword = userPassword;
        }
        public Integer getAge() {
            return age;
        }
        public void setAge(Integer age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
        public Timestamp getSetupTimestamp() {
            return setupTimestamp;
        }
        public void setSetupTimestamp(Timestamp setupTimestamp) {
            this.setupTimestamp = setupTimestamp;
        }
        public Integer getWeightInPounds() {
            return weightInPounds;
        }
        public void setWeightInPounds(Integer weightInPounds) {
            this.weightInPounds = weightInPounds;
        }
        public Integer getHeightInCm() {
            return heightInCm;
        }
        public void setHeightInCm(Integer heightInCm) {
            this.heightInCm = heightInCm;
        }
        public String getDiet() {
            return diet;
        }
        public void setDiet(String diet) {
            this.diet = diet;
        }
        public String getIntolerances() {
            return intolerances;
        }
        public void setIntolerances(String intolerances) {
            this.intolerances = intolerances;
        }
        public Integer getMealId() {
            return mealId;
        }
        public void setMealId(Integer mealId) {
            this.mealId = mealId;
        }
        public Integer getRoutineId() {
            return routineId;
        }
        public void setRoutineId(Integer routineId) {
            this.routineId = routineId;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "UserInfo [userId=" + userId + ", username=" + username + ", userAccountName=" + userAccountName
                    + ", userPassword=" + userPassword + ", age=" + age + ", setupTimestamp=" + setupTimestamp
                    + ", weightInPounds=" + weightInPounds + ", heightInCm=" + heightInCm + ", diet=" + diet
                    + ", intolerances=" + intolerances + ", mealId=" + mealId + ", routineId=" + routineId + "]";
        }



    }
```

Application.properties

```
server.port=8090
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
```

H2 set-up

```
Saved settings: Generic H2(Embedded)
Setting name: Generic H2(Embedded)
Driver Class: org.h2.driver
JDBC URL: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
User Name: sa
```

The application starts normally but the table is not created. I am not getting any message in the console about the table being created.

Comment: download h2 jar http://www.h2database.com/html/download.html and check wether or not the tables are getting created.

Comment: I encountered once this problem and found only two ways to correct it : 1) Use Liquibase with Spring boot to create the table, 2) use a persisting h2 writing on ~/myH2db

Comment: why is persisting h2 writing?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the problem. The problem is the folder structure. Spring boot wasn't able to map the entity classes because they were not included in my basePackageClasses mapping when the application started

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things you can do:-
1. The jdbc related jars present in your local maven repository may be corrupt and the Spring boot build and run is silently not picking them up. (This happened with me) 
Delete the contents of .m2/repository. Post that, run> mvn clean install -DskipTests

2. Also you might want to just put the data.sql file under src/main/resources folder. It gets picked up automatically.
3. Also make sure you put the following in your application.properties file:-

spring.h2.console.enabled=true

Making sure all these things are in place should get you going.